# Why is the "Dynamic" part of Dynamic languages so good?

Tags: dynamic-languages

Jon Skeet posted [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/13/noda-time-gets-its-own-blog.aspx), in which he states that he is going to be asking why the dynamic part of languages are so good. So i thought i'd preemptively ask on his behalf: What makes them so good?

Comment: Community wiki imho

Comment: Just to pre-empt my blog post a bit more: things like REPL and type inference tend to be lumped in with what people like about dynamic languages - but they're not inherently dynamic aspects.

Comment: To add to Jon Skeet's comment, OCaml and Haskell are about as statically typed as you can get, but they come with REPL out of the box. F# is another statically typed language with a REPL and type inference.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/407415#407415

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two fundamentally different approaches to types in programming languages are *static types* and *dynamic types*.  They enable very different programming paradigms and they each have their own benefits and drawbacks.

I'd highly recommend Chris Smith's excellent article [What to Know Before Debating Type Systems](http://www.pphsg.org/cdsmith/types.html) for more background on the subject.

From that article:

> A static type system is a mechanism by which a compiler examines source code and assigns labels (called "types") to pieces of the syntax, and then uses them to infer something about the program's behavior. A dynamic type system is a mechanism by which a compiler generates code to keep track of the sort of data (coincidentally, also called its "type") used by the program. The use of the same word "type" in each of these two systems is, of course, not really entirely coincidental; yet it is best understood as having a sort of weak historical significance. Great confusion results from trying to find a world view in which "type" really means the same thing in both systems. It doesn't. The better way to approach the issue is to recognize that:
>
> - Much of the time, programmers are trying to solve the same problem with
>     static and dynamic types.
> - Nevertheless, static types are not limited to problems solved by dynamic
>     types.
> - Nor are dynamic types limited to problems that can be solved with
>     static types.
> - At their core, these two techniques are not the same thing at all.

Comment: +1 for the link. That's a very insightful article (indeed a highly recommended read!)

Comment: Great response to set the debate.  John is right that many of the things which we equate with dynamic languages are not.

Comment: At that link, i saw the following: "OThe simply-typed lambda calculus, on which all other type systems are based, proves that programs terminate in a finite amount of time. Indeed, the more interesting question is how to usefully extend the type system to be able to describe programs that don't terminate! Finding infinite loops, though, is not in the class of things most people associate with "types," so it's surprising.". I'm fairly sure this is blatantly WRONG as computers are turing machines and i think it's been mathematically proven that not all programs for one can be proven to not halt.

Comment: @RCIX: You need to finish reading the article.  The whole point of a static type system is to *constrain* the program's behavior.  If a program passes the type system constraints, then you can be certain that certain behaviors are not possible.  The drawback is that there may exist programs that would not pass the type constraints but that would still behave the same way, and the type system cannot prove that.  Therefore the purpose of the type system is to reject certain interesting programs, in order to make it possible to prove certain statements about the programs that are left.

Comment: You're correct. Type systems merely prove that programs written under them satsify certain constraints, they say nothing about whether the program will run forever.

Comment: Take the following example: A piece of code that checks whether the result of your static type system's analyzation is successful and then breaks the program if its successful, and if the analyzation fails, it becomes compliant. This will cause your static type system's analyzer to freeze up.

Comment: In other words, any program designed to solve the halting problem will choke on a (modified) version of it's own source code.

Comment: @RCIX: I don't get what your point is.  You're mixing the simply-typed lambda calculus and the Turing model.  Church-Turing thesis only applies to algorithms that terminate; for every computable function, there is a Turing machine, but not vice versa.  There is no contradiction between the halting problem and the statement that "the simply-typed lambda calculus proves that programs terminate in a finite amount of time".  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis#Non-computable_functions for details.

Answer (score 5):

The main thing is that you avoid a lot of redundancy that comes from making the programmer "declare" this, that, and the other.  A similar advantage could be obtained through type inferencing ([boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) does that, for example) but not quite as cheaply and flexibly.  As I wrote in [the past](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-June/087846.html)...:

> complete type checking or inference
>   requires analysis of the whole
>   program, which may be quite
>   impractical -- and stops what Van Roy
>   and Haridi, in their masterpiece
>   "Concepts, Techniques and Models of
>   Computer Programming", call "totally
>   open programming".  Quoting a post of
>   mine from 2004: """ I love the
>   explanations of Van Roy and Haridi, p.
>   104-106 of their book, though I may or
>   may not agree with their conclusions
>   (which are  basically that the
>   intrinsic difference is tiny -- they
>   point to Oz and Alice as interoperable
>   languages without and with static
>   typing,  respectively), all the points
>   they make are good.  Most importantly,
>   I  believe, the way dynamic typing
>   allows real modularity (harder with 
>   static typing, since type discipline
>   must be enforced across module 
>   boundaries), and "exploratory
>   computing in a computation model that 
>   integrates several programming
>   paradigms".
>
> "Dynamic typing is recommended", they
>   conclude, "when programs must be  as
>   flexible as possible".  I recommend
>   reading the Agile Manifesto to 
>   understand why maximal flexibility is
>   crucial in most real-world 
>   application programming -- and
>   therefore why, in said real world
>   rather than in the more academic
>   circles Dr. Van Roy and Dr. Hadidi
>   move in,  dynamic typing is generally
>   preferable, and not such a tiny issue
>   as  they make the difference to be. 
>   Still, they at least show more 
>   awareness of the issues, in devoting 3
>   excellent pages of discussion  about
>   it, pros and cons, than almost any
>   other book I've seen -- most  books
>   have clearly delineated and preformed
>   precedence one way or the  other, so
>   the discussion is rarely as balanced
>   as that;).

Answer (score 3):

I'd start with recommending reading [Steve Yegge's post on Is Weak Typing Strong Enough](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/is-weak-typing-strong-enough), then [his post on Dynamic Languages Strike Back](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/05/dynamic-languages-strike-back.html). That ought to at least get you started!

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a few advantage/disadvantage comparisons:

Dynamic Languages:

- Type decisions can be changed with minimal code impact.
- Code can be written/compiled in isolation.  I don't need an implementation or even formal description of the type to write code.
- Have to rely on unit tests to find any type errors.
- Language is more terse.  Less typing.
- Types can be modified at runtime.
- Edit and continue is much easier to implement.

Static Languages:

- Compiler tells of all type errors.
- Editors can offer prompts like Intellisense much more richly.
- More strict syntax which can be frustrating.
- More typing is (usually) required.
- Compiler can do better optimization if it knows the types ahead of time.

To complicate things a little more, consider that languages such as C# are going partially dynamic (in feel anyway) with the var construct or languages like Haskell that are statically typed but feel dynamic because of type inference.

Comment: Interesting points. However it's been fair well proved that tereseness does not *mathematically 100% always equal* tereseness, but it is true in most cases. Also, you should read http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/is-weak-typing-strong-enough .

Comment: Terseness isn't an intrinsic feature of dynamically typed languages. PHP, classic ASP, JavaScript, and Objective-C are suprisingly bloated languages compared to OCaml, Haskell, SML, and Scala. For what its worth, I usually find my F# is comparably or even more terse than equivalent Python.

Comment: "var" is in no way dynamic - C# 3 is entirely statically typed. (C# 4 *is* going dynamic where you want it to.) "var" is just type inference again. That's why the blog post is going to be about the dynamic side of things, not the other things that often accompany dynamic languages.

Comment: The fact that var is type inferred is why I said "(in feel anyway)".  You are correct that it isn't dynamically typed, but it acts very much like it is.

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic programming languages basically do things at runtime that other languages do at Compile time. This includes extension of the program, by adding new code, by extending objects and definitions, or by modifying the type system, all during program execution rather than compilation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language

Here are some common examples

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Dynamic_programming_languages

And to answer your original question:

They're slow, You need to use a basic text editor to write them - no Intellisense or Code prompts, they tend to be a big pain in the ass to write and maintain.  BUT the most famous one (javascript) runs on practically every browser in the world - that's a good thing I guess.  Lets call it 'broad compatibility'.  I think you could probably get a dynamic language interpretor for most operating systems, but you certainly couldn't get a compiler for non dynamic languages for most operating systems.

Comment: So, for the sake of completeness, what makes this a good approach?

Comment: I highly disagree with this statement and i point you to http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/is-weak-typing-strong-enough

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to offend.  Although this sentence jumped out at me on that page "The strong vs. weak typing issue really gets people worked up." hehe...  Lets say Dynamic Languages serve a purpose.  You wouldn't write a high-transaction stock trading system in one though, would you?

Comment: Well... If i had a good team of programmers, i would most definitely choose a dynamic language. But then that's true of most any language....